# Creating alias for function decorators in Python

Tags: python, python-decorators

In Python function decorators are again functions that are first class citizens, which creates the expectation of assigning and passing around flexibly. In below example

```
def auth_token_not_expired(function):
    @auth_token_right
    def wrapper(req):
        # Some validations
        return function(req)
    return wrapper
```

Now I tried assigning this decorator function to another variable as alias

`login_required = auth_token_not_expired`

Upon inspecting the assignment happens successfully however when I invoke it using `@login_required` syntax it causes `NameError`

```
Exception Type: NameError
Exception Value:    
name 'login_required' is not defined
```

How do we register this `login_required` variable too as decorator?

Comment: You can do what you are trying to do (I checked Python 2.7 and 3.4). Are you sure you are in the right scope? Where exactly are you doing the assignment to `login_required`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You are in the wrong scope.**

Adapting the example from [How to make a chain of function decorators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/how-can-i-make-a-chain-of-function-decorators-in-python)

```
def makeitalic(fn):
    def wrapped():
        return "<i>" + fn() + "</i>"
    return wrapped

@makeitalic
def hello():
    return "hello world"

hello() ## returns <i>hello world</i>
```

Now do the assignment:

```
mi = makeitalic

@mi
def helloit():
    return "hello world"

helloit() ## returns <i>hello world</i>
```